# image fade in then text not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I keep the mouse on image, it should display the text with title and some description. This context is working only for the first image and for the remaining images it's not working.

I used jquery plugin. It's not working. Code below.

What are the changes need to be done, let me know. Thanks in advance

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.hoverGrid = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
      'itemClass': '.item'
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      var hoverGrid = $(this);
      hoverGrid.addClass('hover-grid');
      hoverGrid.find(settings.itemClass).addClass('hover-grid-item');

      $(hoverGrid).find(settings.itemClass).hover(function() {
          $(this).find('div.caption').stop(false, true).fadeIn(200);
        },
        function() {
          $(this).find('div.caption').stop(false, true).fadeOut(200);
        });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#whatever').hoverGrid();
});
```

```css
/*!
     * jQuery Cookiebar Plugin CSS
     * https://github.com/carlwoodhouse/jquery.cookieBar
     *
     * Copyright 2012, Mark Searle, Carl Woodhouse.
     */

.hover-grid .hover-grid-item {
  width: 181px;
  height: 181px;
  margin: 0 18px 18px 0;
  float: left;
  /*-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
}

.hover-grid img {
  /*-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;*/
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.hover-grid-item .caption {
  background-color: #222;
  width: 145px;
  height: 145px;
  padding: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  line-height: 1.1;
  /*-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;*/
}

.hover-grid-item .caption p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div id="whatever">
        <div class="item">
          <img width="181" height="181" src="/images/logo.jpg" alt="my image" title="my image" />
          <div class="caption" style="display: none;">
            <h2>Some Title</h2>
            <p>This is a caption to end all captions</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div id="whatever">
        <div class="item">
          <img width="181" height="181" src="/images/logo.jpg" alt="my image" title="my image" />
          <div class="caption" style="display: none;">
            <h2>Some Title</h2>
            <p>This is a caption to end all captions</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div id="whatever">
        <div class="item">
          <img width="181" height="181" src="/images/logo.jpg" alt="my image" title="my image" />
          <div class="caption" style="display: none;">
            <h2>Some Title</h2>
            <p>This is a caption to end all captions</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].   You say you "used a jquery plugin" - which plugin did you use?  or do you mean you wrote one?

Comment: id should be unique so change `id="whatever"` to `class="whatever"` then use `$('.whatever').hoverGrid();`
`

Comment: where, please explain???

Comment: `$('#whatever')` will only find the *first* `id=whatever` because ids are meant to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique within an html page.  You can change your `id=whatever` to `class=whatever` and then use `$(".whatever")` to apply to all.

Updated snippet:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.hoverGrid = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
      'itemClass': '.item'
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      var hoverGrid = $(this);
      hoverGrid.addClass('hover-grid');
      hoverGrid.find(settings.itemClass).addClass('hover-grid-item');

      $(hoverGrid).find(settings.itemClass).hover(function() {
          $(this).find('div.caption').stop(false, true).fadeIn(200);
        },
        function() {
          $(this).find('div.caption').stop(false, true).fadeOut(200);
        });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.whatever').hoverGrid();
});
```

```css
/*!
     * jQuery Cookiebar Plugin CSS
     * https://github.com/carlwoodhouse/jquery.cookieBar
     *
     * Copyright 2012, Mark Searle, Carl Woodhouse.
     */

.hover-grid .hover-grid-item {
  width: 181px;
  height: 181px;
  margin: 0 18px 18px 0;
  float: left;
  /*-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
}

.hover-grid img {
  /*-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;*/
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.hover-grid-item .caption {
  background-color: #222;
  width: 145px;
  height: 145px;
  padding: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  line-height: 1.1;
  /*-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
     border-radius: 4px;*/
}

.hover-grid-item .caption p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="whatever">
        <div class="item">
          <img width="181" height="181" src="/images/logo.jpg" alt="my image" title="my image" />
          <div class="caption" style="display: none;">
            <h2>Some Title</h2>
            <p>This is a caption to end all captions</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="whatever">
        <div class="item">
          <img width="181" height="181" src="/images/logo.jpg" alt="my image" title="my image" />
          <div class="caption" style="display: none;">
            <h2>Some Title</h2>
            <p>This is a caption to end all captions</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="whatever">
        <div class="item">
          <img width="181" height="181" src="/images/logo.jpg" alt="my image" title="my image" />
          <div class="caption" style="display: none;">
            <h2>Some Title</h2>
            <p>This is a caption to end all captions</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```